# Cannot convert value of type '(PHAsset) -> Void' to expected argument type '(([PHAsset]) -> Void)?'

Tags: swift

I'am not able to rectify this error.

```
let vc = BSImagePickerViewController() self.bs_presentImagePickerController( vc , animated: true, select: {(asset: PHAsset) -> Void in },deselect: {(asset: PHAsset) -> Void in }, cancel: {(assets: PHAsset)-> Void in}, finish: { (assets: PHAsset) -> Void in for i in 0..

    func convertAssetsToImage() -> Void {
        if selectedAssests.count != 0 {
            for i in 0..<selectedAssests.count{
                let manager = PHImageManager.default()
                let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
                var thumbnail = UIImage()
                manager.requestImage(for: selectedAssests[i], targetSize: CGSize(width:200 , height : 200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: option, resultHandler:{(result, info) -> Void in thumbnail = result!
                })

                let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbnail, 0.7)
                let newImage = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.imageArray.append(newImage! as UIImage)
            }

            self.extImageOne.animationImages = self.imageArray
            self.extImageOne.animationDuration = 3.0
            self.extImageOne.startAnimating()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You really should read the guidance on how to ask questions before asking one...

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. Please [edit] your question and copy and paste the relevant code, as text. Clearly point out the line causes the error and include the complete and exact error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared your closures to take a single object of type `PHAsset`, but the API you're using expects your closures to take an array of `PHAsset`s. Rewrite your closures to take a `[PHAsset]` instead of a `PHAsset` and you should solve your problem.

EDIT:

I Googled for the `BSImagePickerViewController` class and found the signature for the API you're trying to use. It looks like:

`func bs_presentImagePickerController(_ imagePicker: BSImagePickerViewController, animated: Bool, select: ((_ asset: PHAsset) -> Void)?, deselect: ((_ asset: PHAsset) -> Void)?, cancel: (([PHAsset]) -> Void)?, finish: (([PHAsset]) -> Void)?, completion: (() -> Void)?)`

As you can see, the `select:` and `deselect:` closures take a single PHAsset, so leave those two as you have them in the code above. The `cancel:` and `finish:` closures both need to be rewritten to take a `[PHAsset]` instead.

Comment: same error even after changing it

Comment: Did you change both of the closures that need an array? Post your updated code and error.